# @FormParam parameter always null in my JAX-RS resource service

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, resteasy, form-parameter

Here is a service that I request with a curl :

```bash
time curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:9080/my/service' -H "Authorization:OAuth MyToken" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "ids=516816b2e4b039526a235e2f,516816b2e4b039526a235e2f"
```

The resource :

```java
@Path("/my")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json", "text/json"})
@Restricted
public class MyResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/service")
    public Map<String ,Object> myService(@FormParam("ids") String myIds) {
       // service things
    }
}
```

That service worked fine, but it suddenly fails. Now the parameter myIds is always null, and the result of the curl is 400 bad request...
I didn't change anything in this resource so it should still be working.
If anybody has an idea, let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `curl`-command, you are posting form data along with the `Content-Type: application/json`. Clearly this data is not valid JSON, hence the 400 bad request.

If you want to post form data, you need to use the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Yes it is, with @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}) and this curl : time curl -i -XPOST 'localhost:9080/my/service'; -H "Authorization:OAuth MyToken" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "ids=516816b2e4b039526a235e2f,516816b2e4b039526a235e2f" it works perfectly. Thank you eiden.